# Android VMD MySQL insert and showing dialog

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

I am trying to do a simple insert from an Android application. I can run my `php` script from the browser by concatenating `?entry="Sample value from browser"`, but when I run the application from Android, I get no insert.

Here is where I am calling the insert class that uses JSON and implements AsyncTask:

```
package us.jtaylorok.android.sqlite.first;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RemoteInsert extends AsyncTask<Void, String,String >{

    protected String TAG;
    protected Context context;
    protected String input;
    protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public RemoteInsert(String i,Context c){
        this.input = i;
        this.context = c;
    }


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //ProgressDialog progressDialog; // = new ProgressDialog(context);

        //progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(,"Please Wait..","Sending data to database", false);
        progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context,"Please Wait..","Sending data to database", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/index.php");
            //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.253.8.88/patient_data/patient_data.php");
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.100.205.72/patient_data/patient_data.php");

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry", "Input from Android"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));                   
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error:  "+e.toString());
        }  

        return "";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss(); 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
}
```

And here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
    // mysql_connect("host","username","password");
    mysql_connect("localhost","user1","mypassword");
    mysql_select_db("test");

    $entry_value = $_REQUEST["entry"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO patientdata (entry) values (".$entry_value.");";
    if( !mysql_query($query) ) { 
        /*insert failed*/ 
    }

    mysql_close();
?>
```

Again, this works perfectly if I call it from the browser, but it throws an exception before implementing `AsyncTask`.

I do get the AVD to display the add and remove, but when I do that there is no request in my *apache2* `access_log` or `error_log`. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe when I granted privileges to user1 it needs to be from something other than localhost. I was able to get the values from $_REQUEST and write them to a text file so either the mysql_query function is flaky which I think I have read that it has been deprecated or there is an issue with the user1@localhost privilege issue when coming from android. I can even get this to work from the running the php file from the browser in android. So any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Resolved configuration issue in my php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I think you have stored php script on local server. So use this **10.0.2.2** while initializing HttpPost instead of your machine's ip address. Its localhost equivalent in android Virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

That was not the issue for this particular problem. The issue was a magic quotes setting in the php.ini

Comment: Answering your own questions is perfectly good. However, this answer does not provide enough details to understand what was going on and how you fixed it. Please consider adding more details to your answer.